# Seeking Advice - Implement Buttons to change displayed text

Tags: html, css, button, text, view

i am super new to HTML and CSS, so any advanced, or even beginner code without any explanation probably wont help me a lot. I cant put code here, so i made pictures:

[image: CSS]
[image: HTML1]
[image: HTML2]

---

`c centers the picture in the bio of the game` n jumps to next line in this game.
³ colors stuff, as well as `2 and` / (2 and / are for specific colors)

I would like to have 4 buttons that change the text a person sees.
So lets say i have Button_1, Button_2, Button_3 and Button_4, i want that under the picture (which is in the "main box", the text changes depending on what button is clicked. I can create those 4 text boxes with different text. That is no problem. I might even get some Buttons without much trouble. What i can't do, is link the viewed Textbox with a button. So if i click Button_2, the Text_Box2 should be viewed and Text_Box1 disappers. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you need to use JavaScript in order to do so. P.s You should make a code snippet and add it to your question rather than adding screenshots of your code.

Comment: Pls. instead of adding screenshots add relevant code snippet required to reproduce the same.

Comment: I was trying to do so, but the website didnt let me. It didn't work and i wasn't able to figure out how to add code snippet, that's why i use screenshot instead

Answer (score 0):

You will need a little bit of JavaScript for doing it.

Like so -

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var $text = document.getElementById("text-change");

  var $btn1 = document.getElementById("one");
  var $btn2 = document.getElementById("two");
  var $btn3 = document.getElementById("three");
  var $btn4 = document.getElementById("four");
  
  $btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $text.innerHTML = "Don't..";
  });
  
  $btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $text.innerHTML = "..stop..";
  });
  
  $btn3.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $text.innerHTML = "..me..";
  });
  
  $btn4.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $text.innerHTML = "..now...";
  });


});
```

```html
<div id="text-change">Some text</div>

<button id="one">Don't</button>
<button id="two">Stop</button>
<button id="three">Me</button>
<button id="four">Now</button>
```

Comment: That seems like a great start to try out. But instead of just a text, can i have a textbox show up instead? I got the code for a box already. I just don't know, if javascript works on this webpage. It is a text based rpg server with its own editor to make css and html code

Comment: You want the output in a textbox? I mean, `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>`?

Comment: So far i have a Mainbox with a picutre. In it, is another textbox with information. And if i click a button, it the inner box should show a different information. So lets say i got a button for his apperance, a button for his skills and a button for his ... race and heritage. If i click a button it should show the specific text with information linked to that button. Oh, and Javascript seems not to be able to be implemented within this editor.

Comment: Oh... ok I understand and that's bad that JS cannot be used there. But I'm really sorry, I have no experience in working with text based rpg server. I have no idea about it. :((

Comment: I can only implement HTML and CSS code. I have seen people use buttons there to change what is viewed, but i just dont know how they made it. And as the website is quite big, viewing the code itself in the browser is not much help either.